# Get Horizontal Scroll on TabLayout

Tags: android

I want to interpolate between two colors while scrolling or "swiping" to the next tab in a TabLayout. To do this, I need some way to know when the user is swiping between tabs. I have tried using TabLayout.OnScrollChangeListener but the method is never called. Is it possible to know when the user is swiping to a new tab and, if so, how?

Edit:

```
libraryTabs.setOnScrollChangeListener(new TabLayout.OnScrollChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollChange(View view, int i, int i1, int i2, int i3) {

            }
        });
```

is never called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think to achieve what you want then you will need a ViewPage 
something like this

```
ViewPager mViewPager;
    TabLayout mSlidingTabs;
    mSlidingTabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    mSlidingTabs.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            Log.w(TAG, "onPageScrolled");
            // do what you want
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            Log.w(TAG, "onPageSelected");
            // do what you want
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            Log.w(TAG, "onPageScrollStateChanged");
            // do what you want
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
          //Do whatever you want here.
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't this only work for when a tab is selected and not when it's scrolled? I'm currently using this method to switch colors between tabs.

Comment: Try the code and see if it swipes. Works fine for me if implemented with ViewPager. Just curious, are you using any tab libraries?